# Adding dependencies to git for use by others when cloning project

Tags: python, git, matplotlib, github

I have a python script that I've pushed to GitHub. I'd like my cohorts to download Python and git and clone my repository without further action needed to run my script. To test things out, I copied a short `matplotlib` graphing script. I added the `matplotlib` submodule to my repo and cloned to computer. When double-clicking on the python file, nothing happens. When I open in PyCharm, it says 'no module named `matplotlib.pyplot`' despite the submodule being added correctly. Is there something else I should do to include this dependency?

What I've tried:
`git submodule add https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git` # add submodule

`clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/("My github page here")`

The python test file and a `matplotlib` folder with all the files from their GitHub page show up in the folder I cloned to.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually do not bundle the source of a dependency within your git repository for a lot of reasons (keeping up with a moving target, having to build it yourself etc).

Instead you use a package manager (either your system's, or python's (most famously `pip`)). That [could be a deep rabbit hole to enter](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line), but if they have python installed (and hopefully `pip`), `python3 -m pip install --user matplotlib` could do the trick.

If you add more dependencies than matplotlib, or want to depend on a specific version of matplotlib, you may want to list your dependencies in [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) and then .. teach your cohorts how to work with that.

---

If you want to go down another rabbit hole, you could look at [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/try), here's an example of a notebook that renders a matplotlib graph: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html